# Can't figure out what is causing this error: C2371

Tags: c++

So I have been working on this pretty simple C++ assignment and I have this error showing up in 2 instances: 'Error 5   error C2371: 'relays' : redefinition; different basic types' and 'Error 5   error C2371: 'call_length' : redefinition; different basic types'. I've been stuck looking over the program for more than an hour and I haven't seen the issue so any help would be appretiated.

Code below:

```
#include <iostream>  //standard input/output C++ stream library
#include <string>    //string library

using namespace std; //using the standard C++ namespace


//  function prototypes
void input(string &, int &, int &);
void process(double &, double &, double &, double &, int, int);
void output(string, int, int, double, double, double);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Function name: input
//  Precondition: 
//  Postcondition:
//  Function Description: 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void input(string & cell_num, int & relays, int & call_length)
{
    cout << "Enter your Cell Phone Number: ";
    cin >> cell_num;
    cout << "Enter the number of relay stations: ";
    cin >> relays;
    cout << "Enter the length of the call in minutes: ";
    cin >> call_length;

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Function name:
//  Precondition:
//  Postcondition:
//  Function Description
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////7
void process(double & tax_rate, double & call_tax, double & total_cost, double & net_cost, int relays, int call_length)
{
    if (1<= relays <=5)
    {
        tax_rate = .01;
    }
    else if(6 <= relays <= 11)
    {
        tax_rate = .03;
    }
    else if(12<= relays <=20)
    {
        tax_rate = .05;
    }
    else if (21<= relays <=50)
    {
        tax_rate = .08;
    }
    else if (relays > 50)
    {
        tax_rate = .12;
    }

    net_cost = (relays / 50.0 * 0.40 * call_length);

    call_tax = net_cost * tax_rate / 100; 

    total_cost = net_cost + call_length;

}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Function name:
//  Precondition:
//  Postcondition:
//  Function Description
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void output(string cell_num, int relays, int call_length, double net_cost, double total_cost, double call_tax)
{
    cout << "*********************************" << endl;

    cout << "Cell Phone Number:  " << cell_num << endl;

    cout << "*********************************" << endl << endl << endl;

    cout << "Number of Relay Stations:   " << relays << endl;

    cout << "Length of Call in Minutes:  " << call_length << endl;

    cout << "Net Cost of Call:  " << net_cost << endl;

    cout << "Tax of Call:   " << call_tax << endl;

    cout << "Total Cost of Call:  " << total_cost << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string cell_num;
    int call_length, relays;
    double tax_rate, call_tax, net_cost, relays, call_length, total_cost;



    input(cell_num, relays, call_length);

    process(tax_rate, call_tax, total_cost, net_cost, relays, call_length);

    output(cell_num, relays, call_length, net_cost, total_cost, call_tax);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The solution in this kind of situation is to tell someone else to take a look at your program. However, this is far away from [SO's policies](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I think you should read the error message that **exactly** says what the error is: **'relays' : redefinition; different basic types.** Look at your code it is what you have done, and it is not permitted by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these statements in main you define call_length and  relays twice at first as variables of type int and then as varaibles of type double.

```
int call_length, relays;
double tax_rate, call_tax, net_cost, relays, call_length, total_cost;
```

Taking into account the function declarations it seems that these variables should be defined as having type int.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says: you have defined the variable `relays` two times. Once as a int, and once as a double.